Number of triples of positive integers $(a, b, c)$ such that $a<b<c<10$ and $a, b, c$ and 10 form sides of a quadrilateral
PRE RMO 2017 Problem 20:

What is the number of triples $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers such that (i) $a<b<c< 10$
and (ii) $a, b, c, 10$ form the sides of a quadrilateral?

Extending the triangular inequality to quadrilaterals, we basically have to find the number of ordered triples $(a,b,c)$ such that $a<b<c<10$ and $a+b+c>10$.
One way is to use systematic counting
When $a=1$ $$b+c \ge 10 $$
$b=2$ $c=9,8$
$b=3$ $c=9,8,7$
$b=4$ $c=9,8,7,6$
$b=5$ $c=9,8,7,6,$
$b=6$ $c=9,8,7$
$b=7$ $c=9,8,$
$b=8$ $c=9 $
Total no. of cases $ = 1+2+3+4+4+3+2=19 $
We count similarly for the rest of the values of $a$ and total answer comes to be $73$.
Though this approach works, but I'm still looking for a better one because if this number was $20$ or $30$ then using this approach might be a tedious task. So, is there a better way to solve questions like this ?

How many sums are 10 or less?

@Empy2 No sum is less than or equal to 10, otherwise it won't form a quadrilateral.

There are ${9\choose3}=84$ possibilities.  So eleven sums 10 or less.  Eleven might be easier to count than 73.

I'm sorry I didn't get you. Can you pls define what has 9C3 possibilities, and how did you get 9C3 ?

Choose three of the numbers from 1 to 9.  They are a, b and c.  You found 73 of them sum to more than 10, so 84-73=11 of them sum to 10 or less.

Ok now I get it. Ya you are right, to check for cases where sum is less than or equal to 10 is actually  a nice way to solve this question. But it still requires systematic counting. So, if 30 was given instead of 10 even this would have been a tedious task. So, I'm looking for an algorithm (if it exists) to solve questions like this.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Let $C(n)$ be the number of ways $a+b+c\le n$ .
Let $B(n)$ be the number of ways $a+b\le n$.
Let $A(n)$ be the number of ways $a\le n$.
$A(n)=n$.
Let $B(n)=B1(n)+B2(n)$ where $B1(n)$ are those with $a=1$ and $B2(n)$ are those with $a\ge2$.
$B1(n)=A(n-2)=n-2$ because $b\ge2$, and we want $a+b=1+b\le n$, or $(b-1)\le n-2$.
$B2(n)=B(n-2)$ because $(a-1)+(b-1)\le n-2$.
So $B(n)=B(n-2)+n-2$.
Let $C(n)=C1(n)+C2(n)$, again $C1(n)$ have $a=1$ and $C2(n)$ have $a\ge2$.
$C1(n)=B(n-3)$ and $C2(n)=C(n-3)$.
So $C(n)=B(n-3)+C(n-3)$.
You can quickly calculate all the $B(n)$, then all the $C(n)$.  Then subtract $C(n)$ from $n-1\choose3$.
